# Iterating a string and checking regexes in Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

Groovy here. I'm trying to iterate over the characters in a string and add them to another string with the following logic:

- If the character is a lowercase character ([a-z]), then just add it to the other string as-is; but...
- If the character *is* uppercase or it is a number ([0-9][A-Z]), then append a single whitespace to the other string, then add it to that other string (so, `" ${theChar}"`)

  - The *exception* to this is in the event that the first char in the string is either uppercase or a number, then we just add it to the other string, again, as-is
- I can't use any 3rd party libs like Commons Lang/WordUtils, etc.

My best attempt has not worked out so great:

```
// We want to convert this to: 'Well Hello There'
String startingStr = 'WellHelloThere'
String special = ''
startingStr.each { ch ->
    if(ch == ch.toUpperCase() && startingStr.indexOf(ch) != 0) {
        special += " ${ch}"
    } else {
        special += ch
    }
}
```

More examples:

```
Starting Str     |      Desired Output
======================================
'wellHelloThere' |      'well Hello There'
'WellHello9Man'  |      'Well Hello 9 Man'
'713Hello'       |      '713 Hello'
```

Any ideas where I'm going awry here?

Comment: Per your rules, I believe the desired output is '7 1 3 Hello' in the 3rd case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below :-

```
String regex = "(?=\\p{Upper})|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"

String s1 = 'wellHelloThere'
String s2 = 'WellHello9Man'
String s3 = '713Hello'

assert s1.split(regex).join(" ") == "well Hello There"
assert s2.split(regex).join(" ") == "Well Hello 9 Man"
assert s3.split(regex).join(" ") == "713 Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following: (see comment about desired output for '713 Hello' and the stated rules)

```
String s1 = 'wellHelloThere'
String s2 = 'WellHello9Man'
String s3 = '713Hello'

def isUpperCaseOrDigit = { it ==~ /^[A-Z0-9]$/ }

def convert = { s ->
    def buffer = new StringBuilder()

    s.eachWithIndex { c, index ->
        def t = c 

        if ((index != 0) && isUpperCaseOrDigit(c)) {
            t = " ${c}"
        }

        buffer.append(t)
    }

    buffer.toString()
}

assert "well Hello There" == convert(s1)
assert "Well Hello 9 Man" == convert(s2)
// this is different than your example, but conforms
// to your stated rules:
assert "7 1 3 Hello" == convert(s3)
```